# How can I create a function that takes arrays optionally as parameters?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define a function like so:

```
const updateNodeTypeByIndex = (index: Vec2 | Vec2[], type: NodeType | NodeType[]) => {
    if (index instanceof Array && type instanceof Array){
        // array param implementation
    } else {
        // regular param implementation
    }
}
```

I'm getting errors with this implementation, so, I'm wondering what the correct way of implementing something like this is?

Comment: Are you trying to use overloads? Where you can only call it with `Vec2, NodeType`, or `Vec2[], NodeType[]`?

Comment: Yes, can I do overloading with the `const` function definition? @caTS

Comment: No, overloads are only available to function declarations. You can either do that, or use generics.

Comment: What is the error your are getting? Also to check if a variable is an array, use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), e.g. `if (Array.isArray(index) && Array.isArray(type))`

Comment: What is `Vec2`? If it's an array, you can't distinguish between `Vec2` and `Vec2[]` by testing whether it's an array.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a function that will accept 2 parameters that need to be either type T or T[] and S or S[], you can create function using generics:

```
function updateNodeTypeByIndex<T, S>(index: T | T[], type: S | S[]) {
   if (index instanceof Array && type instanceof Array) {
     // array param implementation
   } else {
    // regular param implementation
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent using the function with `index: T` and `type: S[]`. Generics are also problematic here, think about what happens if `T` or `S` is an array.

Comment: We don't know what kind of behaviour he wants to implement.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie is correct. I'm looking to implement the function taking either both parameters as arrays or none. I think overloading is the best way but I prefer to use the `const` definition so that doesn't work.

Comment: @IgorTomic How is this any different than what I have?